# Finding $\lim_{L \to \infty} \exp{\frac{T}{L}}\sum_{i=1}^L[ \exp{iA + (i-1)B}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am working on a problem and I have come up with a formula that I would like to simply. WLOG, it looks like the following:

$\exp{\frac{T}{L}}\sum_{i=1}^L[ \exp{iA + (i-1)B}]$

Here, $A,B, T$ are constants. I am trying to find what this equates to if I let $L \rightarrow \infty$.

I am not even sure how to approach this, or even if this has a limiting sum. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you know about the signs of $A$ and $B$? It matters since it determines whether $e^{A+B}$ is greater or less than one.

Comment: This is a reasonable question. I've rolled back the the first version of the question since the edit vastly changed the content of the question. This is not a good thing to do, as it makes the answers to the original question suddenly out of date. It is more appropriate to ask an additional question, or to parse the answers to this question and try to answer the question on your own.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^L \exp(iA+(i-1)B) = \exp(A)\frac{\exp(L(A+B))-1}{\exp((A+B))-1}.$$

So, your answer is $$\exp\left(\frac{T}{L}\exp(A)\frac{\exp(L(A+B))-1}{\exp((A+B))-1}\right).$$

For $A+B>0$, $\exp(L)/L$ diverges and thus the result diverges, and thus the required term is infinite if $T>0$, one if $T=0$, and zero if $T<0$.

For $A+B=0$, the result is $\exp(T\exp(A))$.

For $A+B<0$, the result is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could just write $$e^{iA+(i-1)B}=e^A e^{(i-1)(A+B)}=e^A\left(e^{A+B}\right)^{i-1}$$ So, define $x=e^{A+B}$ This makes $$\sum_{i=1}^L e^{iA+(i-1)B}=e^A\sum_{i=1}^L x^{i-1}=e^A\sum_{i=0}^L x^{i}=e^A\,\frac{x^{L+1}-1}{x-1}$$ where you recognize a classical summation which converges to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ if $x<1$ (that is to say if $A+B<0$).